# Ember.Select and Ember.Router

Tags: ember.js

I'm playing around with *Ember.Router*. After going through the excellent sample [canonical-emberjs-routing-example](https://github.com/KasperTidemann/canonical-emberjs-routing-example) by Kasper Tidemann I think I mostly got it.

However I'm wondering how I would best combine this with *Ember.Select*.
Use-case: I want to the user to be able to select the module from a drop-down and then route to the right module.

How about reopening *Ember.Select* and overriding *valueDidChange*?
Any better way to do that?

```
Em.Select.reopen({
  valueDidChange: Ember.observer(function() {
    this._super();
    console.log('selection changed');
    App.router.transitionTo(this.get('value'))
  }, 'value')
});
```

Comment: If you re-open `Em.Select`, you're gonna apply your changes to all `Select` controls in your Ember app. You might want to create a view that extends `Ember.Select` and then you override the `valueDidChange` method

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe you should post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my comment:

> if you re-open Em.Select, you're gonna apply your changes to all Select
>   controls in your Ember app. You might want to create a view that
>   extends Ember.Select and then you override the valueDidChange method

I meant something *similar* to this

```
var RoutableSelect = Ember.Select.extend({
    valueDidChange: Ember.observer(function() {
        this._super();
        App.router.transitionTo(this.get('value'))
    }, 'value');
});
```

This way you don't override the original functionality of the `Ember.Select` for the rest of your app. And now you can use `RoutableSelect` for the particular view you want this functionality to exit.

Comment: I think you could declare this  as App.RoutableSelect, It's a meaningful name for this stuff, isn't it ?

Comment: the name can be whatever you want, but yeah, it's better name for sure